# Ionic 3 application - how to make font size independent of native settings?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing an Ionic 3 application, I recently published it and in production, where phones of all kinds and sizes were used, I noticed that there is an android native setting called "font-size" where you can make the size of texts in your phone bigger or smaller.

Some people (among others many older people) choose 'big' or even 'huge' text size. This unfortunately affects texts in my application on their phones and completely ruins the layout.

The way I am defining font sizes in my css files is with em values, but I also tried px.
Do you know if there is any way to prevent my application from adhering to this native android text-size setting? Or any other ways to fix it?
Please help,
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution! I used this phonegap plugin:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/mobile-accessibility/

and used the method `this.mobileAccessibility.usePreferredTextZoom(false);`

This way, my app ignores the android font size settings!

Comment: For me, changing the current value of text zoom to 100% worked well: `this.mobileAccessibility.setTextZoom(100);`

Answer (score 1):

The plugin suggested in the accepted answer was last updated in 2016. Instead of adding a new plugin, we can configure the webview settings to disable text zoom as discussed [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/font-size-difference-caused-by-android-font-size-settings/49200/7?u=ajainfyle).

So, inside `MainActivity.java` you can do something like this:

```java
import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    WebSettings settings = bridge.getWebView().getSettings();
    settings.setTextZoom(100);
    settings.setSupportZoom(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I face similar issue. I have done as below for best practice :

```
this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
   this.mobileAccessibility.getTextZoom().then((textZoom)=>{
      if(textZoom>130){
          this.mobileAccessibility.setTextZoom(130); 
      }
   }); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting text zoom with JS works with a jump from big to small size. But in MainActivity.java it applies immediately without visible delay

```
package io.ionic.starter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();

    webSettings.setTextZoom(100);
  }
}
```

Comment: error: package R does not exist
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);